# json and javascript issue

Tags: javascript, json

I have a issue with parsing JSON object value. My javascript is returning undefined.

My Json object look like

```
    {
   "doc":[
      {
         "folderId":"100",
         "zipCode":"",
         "bondNumber":"",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":"Tst0.txt"
      },
      {
         "folderId":"101",
         "zipCode":"34745",
         "bondNumber":"",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":" "
      },
      {
         "folderId":"102",
         "zipCode":"45653",
         "bondNumber":"",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":""
      },
      {
         "folderId":"103",
         "zipCode":"",
         "bondNumber":"343",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":""
      },
      {
         "folderId":"104",
         "zipCode":"",
         "bondNumber":"53",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":""
      },
      {
         "folderId":"104",
         "zipCode":"",
         "bondNumber":"67",
         "dateCreated":" ",
         "fileName":""
      }
   ]
};
```

my Javascript

```
//ITs in JSP <tbody id="docListTable"> 
var docsTable = document.getElementById("docListTable"), 

var docs = document.getElementById("docList"); 
//ITs  <input type="hidden" id="docList" name="docList" value="<%= request.getAttribute("docList")%>"/> in JSP 
docsTable.innerText = ""; 
for (var x in docs) { 
var row = docsTable.insertRow(); 
var cell = row.insertCell(); 
cell.style.align = "middle"; 
cell.innerHTML = "<input title=\"Add to move document list\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"deleteDoc\" id=\"deleteDoc\" value=\"" + docs[x].folderId + "\">"; 

cell = row.insertCell(); 
cell.style.textAlign = "center"; 
cell.innerText = ((docs[x].zipCode == "") ? " " : docs[x].zipCode); 

cell = row.insertCell(); 
cell.style.textAlign = "center"; 
cell.innerText = ((docs[x].bondNumber == "") ? " " : docs[x].bondNumber); 

cell = row.insertCell(); 
cell.style.textAlign = "center"; 
cell.innerText = docs[x].dateCreated; 
}
```

In my table all values are undefined and its returning only one row.
I believe its not able to parse json string.
I formatted my object to json string in my action class.

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you provide a js fiddle please, this would be great.

Comment: `for (var x in docs) { ` doesn't make sense...`docs` is a single element.

Comment: Did you mean to do `var docs = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("docList").value).doc;`?

Comment: This would cause a JS runtime error if the JSON document somehow doesn't have a "doc" field.

Comment: @stubailo: No, it wouldn't .

Comment: @Kevin docs is not a single element. IT has more than 1 row

Comment: id's cant be used more than once, you selected by id therefore only one element was returned.

Comment: @sarmachinta: You wrote in the comment yourself: `ITs <input type="hidden" id="docList" name="docList" value="<%= request.getAttribute("docList")%>"/>`. Looks pretty much like a single element. Are you saying there are more than one of these `input` elements?

Comment: @Felex its formatted json string 
while(it.hasnext()){docObj=(DocObj)it.next();
buffer.append("{\"folderId\":\"");
buffer.append(String.valueOf(bondDoc.getFolderId()));

Comment: Why not use a JSON library to serialize your data instead of writing your own output function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want at the beginning:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("docList").value);
var docs = data && data.doc;

for (var x in docs) {
// the rest of your code
```

1. Calling `.value` makes sure you get the value property, not just the
   HTML element
2. JSON.parse translates the string that you got out using
   `.value` into an object
3. Using `data && data.doc` makes it so that
   your code doesn't error if data is null for some reason (for example
   the JSON document didn't get returned properly)

Comment: an explanation on what JSON.parse does and why he needs to do it will help the asker learn.

Comment: Your third point is not correct. If `JSON.parse` cannot parse the JSON, it throws a syntax error. If you really want to guard against this, you have to use a `try .. catch` block.

Answer (score -1):

You have to actually eval the JSON string to get a Javascript Object:

```
var docs = eval(document.getElementById("docList").value);
```

Comment: No he doesn't, he can (and should) use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I guess that depends on whether he needs to support IE < 8.

Comment: Also, the list is actually not at the root of the JSON so you wouldn't be able to iterate over docs.